# Consider defining a bean of type 's.safontseva.mynotes.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I copied that code from another project, and it worked there.

[image]

In my project I've
created all the
classes that are needed but I have this mistake. When I type `@Bean` (instead of `@Component`, but in the original project it worked without any annotation) above *UserRepository.class* it underlines as a mistake

Why doesn't my code work? How to solve the mistake which appears when I run my application?

```
package s.safontseva.mynotes.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/success")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/logout", "POST"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider () {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

The Service which uses UserRepository

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn't exist"));
        return SecurityUser.fromUser(user);
    }
}
```

The Repository:

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: First of all you can remove @Component from the repository. How does your package structure look like?

Comment: https://github.com/proselytear/springsecuritycourse - original project

Comment: And what's the difference in your project that doesn't work?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I deleted `@Component. `The project structure photo has been added. The difference between my project and copies is in that I haven't written rest controllers in rest package, but I don't think that it affects because I have a controller which processes requests to login page and success page, they are used in configure method

Comment: That's very stragne! Can you shre your project?